# Posting on Facebook Page and showing its update to users

Tags: android, facebook, post, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to post the data from my android app. The data is getting properly posted on the Facebook Page, but to the user's who had joined / liked that page they are not getting proper update.
From the below images you will understand it more clearly.

[image: Data posted on the Facebook Page]

[image: Data which is available to the user]

The first image shows the data which is getting posted on the FaceBook Page. This is working properly, but the 2nd image is the image which is displayed to the user, but it is appearing blank, only the app name is coming but the other details are not appearing.
Can any one Help me please, it will be very Helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?

Comment: Not exactly but i had made changes in the web services (php) so that we can get the similar format as previous. The problem was of link, if we remove the link it shows properly.